# VMSS Autoscaling: WADPerformanceCounters

Tags: azure-vm-scale-set

I’ve added the autoscaling settings to my ServiceFabric template and after deploying it, the portal shows that auto scale is configured, but what I am not able to see is the table WADPerformanceCounters;  mentioned in the documentation; in my storage account. So how is the auto scaling executed without the information about the couters?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If autoscale cannot find the data it's configured to look at, it will set your capacity equal to the "default" configured in the autoscale rule.

As for what could explain the behavior you're seeing, here are a couple hypotheses:

1) There are two types of metrics in Azure today: host and guest; host metrics live in Azure-internal data stores and as such don't require a storage account to store data in. Guest metrics, however, do live in a storage account. So depending on how you added autoscale, you might have added host metrics instead of guest metrics? For more info, see this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/insights-autoscale-common-metrics

2) As you can see in [this template using guest metrics](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-vmss-automation-dsc/azuredeploy.json), for guest metrics the scale set must have the WAD extension configured to point to the storage account; it's probably worth checking that the storage account specified in the WAD extension config is the same storage account you looked for the table in.

Answer (score 0):

For host metrics, you can find the list of supported metrics here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics#microsoftcomputevirtualmachinescalesets

For guest metrics, as mentioned above you need to configure the Windows Azure Diagnostic (WAD) extension correctly on your VMSS. Specifically autoscale engine will query from the WAD{value}PT1M{value} tables in your configured diagnostic storage account.  These tables contain the local 1 minute aggregation of the performance counter data.